# p:message attached to a h:form

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I have two forms in my page, in the first formulary are input fields with validation, and in the other a dataTable. The first formulary has a message area to show validation errors, and the second formulary has a message area to show problems with the retrieval of the data (this message area is updated from myController.search).:

```
    <h:form id="form1">
        <p:message id="messageForm1" for=":form1" />
        <p:inputText id="text1" value="#{myBean.data}" required="true" />
                    ....
        <p:commandButton value="Search" actionListener"#{myController.search}"
            update=":form2:dataTable :form2:messageForm2 :form1:messageForm1" process="text1, ..." />
    </h:form>

    <h:form id="form2">
        <p:message id="messageForm2" for="messageForm2" />
        <p:dataTable>
        ...
        </p:dataTable>
    </h:form>
```

The problem is that the messages in the form2 are working, but the validation messages in form1 are never shown

Comment: Why do you have colon in first `<p:message >`?Is it a typo?

Comment: no, I just wanted to reference the absolute path to the formulary

Answer (score 2):

The description of the `for` attribute of the `p:message` tag says:

> Id of the component whose messages to display.

So you can't specify the ID of the form. You have to specify the ID of a single form component. e.g. `<p:message id="messageForm1" for="text1" />`. But then you have to create one message element for every form component.

An alternative would be to use the `p:messages` tag. For examples see here: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/messages.jsf

Comment: Thanks for the info. About using messages, the problem is that when I have an error in the second formulary, I get the error in both message components

Comment: I have found also a tutorial http://www.javaranch.com/journal/2004/04/JSF_Part1.html where they use a h:message for="formulary", so it should work